# getting superuser permissions when I'm on an "administrator" account

Tags: 12.04, java

I'm trying to install the java plugin for mozilla. I have followed the instructions on the java website, but when I try to create the link to the mozilla directory, I get 'permission denied'. I'm logged on as the administrator. Is there a command I need to enter to act as administrator in terminal? I'm running 12.04 lts

Answer (score 2):

When you say "logged on as the administrator" I think you mean as a regular user with some special group memberships and `sudo` ability to run commands as the superuser "root".

In the "User Accounts" control panel this is what "administrator" means, as contrasted with "standard" accounts which can't escalate privileges.

As [chaskes answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/302272/1078), even "administrator" accounts normally run as a regular user to increase security and avoid mistakes. You need to ask permission with `sudo` to get superuser privileges for the duration of a command.

Answer (score 1):

You want to preface the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo ln -s <rest of command>
```

You will be prompted for your password. Please note that when you type your password you will not see anything echoed back to the screen.